# javascript append an option to select

Tags: javascript, html, function

I implemented this function to add days to select list according to the month selected 
but it doesn't work.

```
function daysInMonth() {
  var year = document.getElementById(year).value;
  var month = document.getElementById(month).value;
  var dayscount = new Date(year,month, 0).getDate();
  var select = document.getElementById(day);
  for (var c = 1 ;  c <= dayscount ; c++){
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = c ;
    select.appendChild(option);
  }
}
```

and here's the html:

```
<select name="evmonth" id = "month" onchange="daysInMonth()">
```

Comment: id is included within double quotes document.getElementById("year").value;

Comment: Did you check your console to see if there were any error messages?

Comment: Second that advice! This is one of a very large category of bugs where you would see an error message in the console telling you exactly what the error is. Simply load your page in Chrome, open the Developer Tools, and run your code. (Either reload the page, or interact with the page as needed to trigger the buggy code. Then look for error messages in the Console tab. While there, check out the Sources tab where you can interact and inspect your code and data in great detail. Most mysterious bugs can be tracked down this way.

Comment: DOM manipulation calls for jQuery. Use that, its only requires you to use a <script> tag to include a jquery.js file. Then you create an option with var option = $('<option/>'); you append with select.append(option);

Comment: Oh, and you use var year = $('#year').val(); pretty isnt it?

Comment: I see that you use getElementByID(year) instead of getElementByID("year") in your code, you need to pass a string, but I also see thats corrected in the answers

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment:

You can use the [Option constructor](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-option-tvd) to save yourself some typing:

```
for (var c = 1 ;  c <= dayscount ; c++){
  select.appendChild(new Option(c));
}
```

It's also more widely supported than `document.createElement`, but likely you don't care about such old browsers.

Also, instead of creating 28 to 31 new options every time, consider just adding and removing the last 3 as required, e.g.:

```
<script>

function update(el) {
    var dayscount = el.value;
    var daysSelect = el.form.days;
    var daysLength = daysSelect.length;
    daysSelect.length = daysLength > 28? 28 : daysLength;

    while (daysSelect.length < dayscount) {
      daysSelect.appendChild(new Option(daysSelect.length + 1));
    }
}

</script>

<form>
  <select name="monthLength" onchange="update(this);">
    <option value="28">28
    <option value="29">29
    <option value="30">30
    <option value="31">31
  </select>

  <select name="days">
  </select>
</form>
```